# An $n-1$ dimensional surface has $n$ dimensional measure $0$.

Tags: measure-theory, manifolds

How does one show this? I was thinking that on an $(n-1)$ dimensional surface there a local homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which can be canonically embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$, and it seems clear then that this image has $n$ dimensional measure $0$, but I also know that homeomorphisms don't have to preserve measure $0$ sets. The result is clearly true for boxes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since a box can clearly only be an $(n-1)$ surface if one of the sides has $0$ length, but I'm not sure if this alone can be used to prove it.

Edit: Actually I'm not sure what the precise conditions are for this to be true, so I guess part of my question is when is it true? You can assume it's a smooth embedding, or anything else needed.

Comment: Does the definition of surface maybe include a differentiability condition?

Comment: I imagine some smoothness is required.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. This isn't a question from a book exactly so maybe the statement I wrote wasn't right.

Comment: It's unquestionably true for a $C^1$ submanifold. I would surmise that it's false for wildly embedded topological manifolds.

Comment: What @TedShifrin said. There are Jordan curves with positive area (Osgood, 1902), and if you have no better idea, take a product of such a thing with $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ for a higher-dimensional topological hypersurface of positive $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. What about the Alexander Horned Sphere?

Comment: @TedShifrin Not sure. I thought the point of that was simple connectedness (or rather, not), I wouldn't be surprised if it (necessarily) has positive Lebesgue measure, but I don't know.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, there's Cantor-like behavior which makes the complement very, very multiply-connected, even though the interior is still a ball. I wonder if the sphere has larger Hausdorff dimension, but I've never seen this addressed.